# traffic manager Azure endpoint public IP address

Tags: azure, endpoint

We have 2 IP addresses with DNS name but in different Azure subscription. Currently we want to add both Public IP address in one traffic manager endpoint.

But when we start to select public IP address, it only display candidate IP address in current subscription, while can't see IP address in other subscripion.

Is there any way that can add Public IP address in other subscription to this traffic manager endpoint?

Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to use the subnet routing or multivalue routing?

Answer (score 0):

We can make this through PowerShell CLI:

New-AzTrafficManagerEndpoint -EndpointStatus Enabled -Name "EndpointName" -ProfileName "TrafficManagerProfileName" -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroupName" -Type AzureEndpoints -Priority  -TargetResourceId ""